# External jar crashes after being launched

Tags: java, freeze, launcher

I'm currently working on a little 2D Game and because I'm lazy and don't want to always send the newest version of the game to my friends I made a launcher that keeps the game updated by downloading the newest version from an FTP-Server if their version is outdated. This works just fine. But then there's a problem with the game itself.

This is how I start my game:

```
File file = new File(directory + sep + "thegalidor.jar");
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
if(!isOffline){ //If the player has no connection they can still play the game in offline-mode
  if(!txtUser.getText().isEmpty() && txtPw.getPassword() != null){
    if(Downloader.getCanLogin(txtUser.getText(), txtPw.getPassword())){ //The player has to login first, if they have a connection to the FTP-Server
      try {
        desktop.open(file);
        System.exit(0);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
} else {
  try {
    desktop.open(file);
    System.exit(0);
  } catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The dircetory variable is set to user.home + the directory the game files are saved in. The sep variable is just the OS-specific file.seperator. The game launches without any problems and I can play the game like it should be. I can load in a save file or start a new save file. But when I try to save the game it just freezes without any output.

This is my save method:

```
public static void saveGame() {
  URL resource = Main.class.getResource(saveFile);
  File file;
  BufferedWriter bw;

  try {
    file = new File(resource.toURI());

    file.delete();
    file.createNewFile();

    bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)));

    Level level = gsManager.getClientLevel();

    bw.write(level.getPath());
    bw.newLine();

    bw.write(level.getPlayer().getXPos() + " " + level.getPlayer().getYPos() + " " + level.getPlayer().getHealth());

    bw.close();
  } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The save file is in the game jar and when I launch the game without the launcher everything works as it should, it only freezes when I start it using the launcher and then want to save my game.
Is there any way I can stop my game from freezing all the time?

Comment: you cant edit stuff inside the jar during runtime

Comment: Somehow it works in debug mode in eclipse, but that seems to be the problem, thanks

Comment: im not sure about this but i dont eclipse actually makes a jar to run the files there is no real reason for it too do that.

Comment: Just FYI, the reason it runs in Eclipse is because Eclipse does not make a jar from the project, it runs the files in the bin directory. So file operations on the resources in the classpath work in Eclipse. But they don't work in the distributed application. This is something I have to train out of all my developers. You cannot mix the classpath resources and File operations.